# Magento 2 buy x and y get free sku product

Tags: magento2

I would like to know how to set cart price rule as

Buy X and Y get free sku product

for example,
if buy x qty = 1 , y qty = 1 then it should get 1 free product
if buy x qty = 2 , y qty = 2 then it should get 2 free product

it look like buy set product item (x and y)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no out-of-the-box Magento cart price rule that will fulfill your requirement. The [Buy X get Y free](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-buy-x-get-y-free.html) default rule can be used only for multipliers of the same product (same sku, not multiple and not combined with other skus), example - `Buy X quantity of product from category A, get Y quantity of the same product for free.`

For your requirement, you will need to either write a customization for this, or to integrate a 3rd party module from the Magento marketplace.

Good luck!